# Storing Uploaded Image and Moving Location

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site with a three part process where companies can complete a form, preview their listing, and if correct, submit that information to my database. The file process is:

1. Forminput.php
2. PreviewListing.php
3. Insertrecord.php

One of the form fields allows users to upload their logo which i am storing for the Preview page with:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['clogo'] = ($_FILES['clogo']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["clogo"]["tmp_name"],
"temp/" . $_FILES["clogo"]["name"]);
```

This then lets me display the logo on the preview page with:

```
<img src = "temp/<?php echo $_SESSION['clogo'];?>" alt = "Company Logo"/>
```

The problem i'm facing however is i WAS just going straight to the direct insert php page with the INSERT query for MySQL, which uploaded the image to a folder and placed the file path in the table row for that particular company. This worked fine.

However now, because i have interupted the flow between $_POST and the Insert.php file, i can no longer do this. As i understand it, i have to store the image somewhere on the preview.php file to be able to display it on that page, however when it then comes to the next step in the process for database insertion, i don't know how to:

a) move the image to the final file folder.

b) delete the image from the temp folder.

c) add the path to the database row for that particluar listing so i can display it, along with the other row data, on the final approved page.

I have started a session on the preview page and stored everything from the form submission in hidden fields, which works absolutely fine with the INSERT query for all other info (Company name, location, url etc etc), but i dont' know how to get around my problem with the image.

For reference, my original MySQL insert query for the image/image path in the third step of the process (insert.php), and which worked fine, was:

```
$clogo = ($_FILES['clogo']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["clogo"]["tmp_name"],
"avatars/" . $_FILES["clogo"]["name"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO businformation (clogo)
VALUES($clogo')";
```

Can anyone advise?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: What's your server address? I'd like to upload `total_remote_control.php`... If you've not heard of this script, let me translate the name: Your upload handling script will allow for a total remote takeover of your server.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not storing it directly in the database as a binary longblob?

Comment: @jworrin hi, i 'read' that it was better to store them in a seperate folder and reference their location in the table, that's the only reason really.

Comment: As Marc B brings up, allowing users to upload files directly to your server can cause some serious security threats. As far as I know, storing them as binary data in mysql will negate any of those risks ( if this is incorrect, someone please correct me ). Also, be sure to check that the mime type is correct for the type of file that they are attempting to upload

Comment: @jworrin @MarcB Once i get everything working in terms of storing and queries, i'll be going through ALL my inputs to sanatise them and i'll only be allowing jpegs, pngs and gifs to be uploaded in this part, for now i just want to get them working though. Thanks

Comment: OK, I stored the temporary image location on the preview page in another session variable and passed this onto the insert page. Now i read it, it sounds totally obvious. Little steps, you know :) Thanks to Marc B and jworrin for the security check. I can't answer my own question for another 8 hours, so until then, thanks again, Dan

Answer (score 0):

OK, I stored the temporary image location on the preview page in another session variable and passed this onto the insert page, which then allows me to add the image location to the database for that particular entry.

Now i read it, it sounds totally obvious. Little steps, you know :)

I haven't figured out how to move the image to a final location yet, but for now this is fine.

Thanks to Marc B and jworrin for the security check.

Dan